# What to do when a tag excerpt has a single word that is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I was looking at the following tag excerpt for Mule ESB:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mule/info

The description starts: "Mule ESB is a lightweight Java-based enterprise service bus (ESB)" and seems to be taken from the vendor web site.

The problem however, is that the general consensus in the area of enterprise integration, is that an "ESB" is the exact opposite to "lightweight".

So I tried to edit the tag, and suggest removing the word "lightweight", e.g. "Mule ESB is a Java-based enterprise service bus (ESB)".

My edit was rejected, perhaps because it was too minor (yet being lightweight or not, and even more incorrectly saying so, is a major point) and also perhaps because it says "lightweight" all over the vendor web site.

What to do in this situation? It would be great to have resolved once and for all, is an E.S.B. "lightweight" (when by nature, an ESB is extremely heavy) - and if so, how so?

Comment: Maybe lightweight is used here in the context of ESB not in the context of enterprise integration?

Comment: Well there is a movement in recent years away from ESB's to "lightweight integration frameworks". An ESB is generally not at all considered lightweight, no matter if it is relatively "lighter" than another ESB.

Comment: "We need an ESB" "Damnit, those are so involved to set up and complicated."  "I agree, let's look for a lightweight implementation." "We CAN'T, thanks to vikingsteve here!"  "vikingsteve, why did you have to screw us over like this? What did we ever do to deserve you pronouncing upon high that there is no such thing as a lightweight ESB? Now you're going to cost us thousands in man hours!" "We're going to go out of business and I won't be able to feed my children.  I'm jumping off the roof.  Thanks, vikingsteve."

Comment: Lol, have to say - most emotion filled response I've ever seen on a post. Think this will be my first and *last* post on meta...

Answer (score 2):

That wiki is wrong for today's [wiki guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

It reads as an advertisement which is not the aim of tag wiki's. It could assume people already know the product because that is why they arrived here. The tag wiki should help them in deciding if THIS tag should be used on their question and should help them in finding duplicates and related off-site material.

If you ONLY remove a single word (being factual correct or not is I think besides the point) is rejected as *no improvement what so ever*.

Feel free to overhaul that complete wiki and edit it into something useful. In that process *lightweight* will vanish for sure....